# A toggle function for different buttons

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make two different buttons in vanilla JavaScript that, when clicked one after the other, display a different text message.

Any advice in reorganising the code below? Thanks.

I could find a toggle function for one button but not for different buttons.

index.html

```
<button onclick="revealMessageUk()"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/uk.svg" id="1"/></li></button>

<button onclick="revealMessageSpain()"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/spain.svg" id="3"/></li></button>


<p id="hiddenMessageUk" style="display:none">Hello!</p>

<p id="hiddenMessageSpain" style="display:none">¡Hola!</p>
```

index.js

```
function revealMessageUk() {
  document.getElementById('hiddenMessageUk').style.display = 'block';
}

function revealMessageSpain() {
  document.getElementById('hiddenMessageSpain').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I'd like to not only display like hereafter but have a sort of a toggle function (hide/show or add/remove feature) for the two foreign languages below.

Comment: what stops you from `.style.display='none';` for another `<p>`?

Comment: I've been on this forum from only lately. I hope that I can help others too very soon like you all do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```js
function revealMessage(msg) {
  hiddenMessage.style.display='block';
  hiddenMessage.innerText=msg;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="revealMessage('Hello!')"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/uk.svg" id="1" alt='UK'/></li></button>

<button onclick="revealMessage('¡Hola!')"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/spain.svg" id="3" alt='ES'/></li></button>

<p id="hiddenMessage" style="display:none"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamil and the others too of course. Problem solved. Your code works wonders. I don't know you people come up with such clear-cut ideas.

Comment: @timotom experience :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to toggle, but also keep it flexible when more locales will be added. You keep a sort of a selectedLocaleId "state" and change it when one of the buttons is clicked with the corresponding locale id.

```js
let selectedLocaleId;

function selectLocale(newSelectedLocaleId) {
  // If there is a selected locale id,  un-select it
  if (selectedLocaleId) {
    document.getElementById(selectedLocaleId).style.display = 'none';
  }
  // set the new selected locale id
  selectedLocaleId = newSelectedLocaleId;
  document.getElementById(selectedLocaleId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="selectLocale('hiddenMessageUk')"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/uk.svg" id="1"/></li></button>

<button onclick="selectLocale('hiddenMessageSpain')"><li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/spain.svg" id="3"/></li></button>


<p id="hiddenMessageUk" style="display:none">Hello!</p>

<p id="hiddenMessageSpain" style="display:none">¡Hola!</p>
```

Hope this helps :)

Cheers